# Visual C++ - how can I turn a unicode character into char or string?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, unicode, character-encoding, ascii

To get a string of the Greek letter µ in my Visual C++, I can enter `"µ"` or use the <s>ASCII</s> CP-1252 code 181 by e.g. `std::string(1, 181)` (and as a sidenote, this displays correctly in the GUI as µ). The unicode sequence `"\u03BC"` just turns into a question mark (a proper ASCII question mark which equals `std::string(1, 63)`, not something else which is shown as a question mark).

Why does Visual C++ converts the unicode for µ into something else when µ is in fact supported? Can I enter the unicode character U+03BC or \u03BC into my code in some other way to get µ, or do I have to stick to something like `std::string(1, 181)`?

Comment: Show full code for the `\u03BC` case. Use UTF-8 everywhere (source code, `u8` literal,  compiler options, console codepage) to be sure and portable.

Comment: `\u03BC` has a value of 1674 which is far to large to fit in a single char.  that `181` worked for you is not portable.

Comment: 181 cannot ever be ASCII as it is above 128. 181 (or 0xb5) happens to map to µ in the default windows CP1252 codepage. If you switch your console to a different codepage you will get something else. For example Japanese users with codepage 932 might see a ｵ instead.

Comment: @Botje `std::string("\u03BC") == std::string(1, 63)` is 1.

Comment: @Botje I used this table: https://www.ascii-code.com/

Comment: The part that is called "extended ASCII codes" is not ASCII, and as it says in the paragraph: "The table below is according to Windows-1252 (CP-1252)".  Windows-1252 is not Unicode.  Use UTF-8 everywhere.  Try not to mix-and-match code pages.

Comment: @Eljay Thanks; I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @H.v.M. not on my system. There it results in a UTF-8 codepair `\316\274` or `ce bc` in hex. You are writing unportable code. Turning the unrepresentable 0x3BC 16-bit character into a question mark is a valid thing for your compiler to do. Although I would hope it gives you warnings about doing so... Do you have warnings turned on and/or are you looking at them?

Comment: Visual C++ converts the Unicode `µ` to `?` because you are not using UTF-8 everywhere.  CP-1252 (Latin) is not CP-65001 (UTF-8).

Comment: `std::string("\u03BC") == std::string(1, 63)` produces `warning C4566: character represented by universal-character-name '\u03BC' cannot be represented in the current code page` If you want to encode binary sequences then you should store them byte by byte: `std::string("\xCE\xBC")` or use dedicated utf-8 string literal type `u8"\u03BC"`

Comment: Thanks, I do see that warning and `u8"\u03BC"` is the answer I was looking for. Unfortunately it doesn't display correctly, while `std::string(1, 181)` does. I can't access the GUI code so I guess my best bet is to continue doing what works and write a ticket.

Comment: @H.v.M. It's not the code's fault that it does not display correctly, it's because your console is set to use CP-1252. If you change your console to use UTF-8 then `u8"\u03BC"` will display correctly. First decide which console settings you want to use, CP-1252 or UTF-8 (or something else), change your console to use that setting. Only then write the code for that setting.

Comment: `std::string` doesn't support UTF.  It's built to deal with single elements of type char.  A UTF character might take up multiple `char`s in order to hold its entire encoding.  You either need a Unicode library like ICU or you need to start using `wstring`.

Comment: You should perhaps convert between encodings (in the hell of mix of various codebases used) on Windows with Windows API functions MultiByteToWideChar and WideCharToMultiByte.

Comment: @NathanOliver `std::string` is the simplest way to store UTF-8 though.

Comment: @NathanOliver `std::wstring` doesn't support Unicode any more than `std::string` does. By definition the contents of any string are encoded somehow, and Unicode is not an encoding.

Comment: @john Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. In this case, though, it's to be displayed in a GUI which I can't change, not a console.

Comment: @H.v.M. OK then it looks like you have to stick with CP-1252

Comment: Note the difference - `µ` (U+00B5,  *Micro Sign*)
vs. `μ` (U+03BC,  *Greek Small Letter Mu*).

Comment: @JosefZ Yes, thank you! `"\u0085"` works in CP-1252, or `u8"\u0085"` in UTF-8.

Comment: @JosefZ ... actually I just tried `"\u0085"`, `u8"\u0085"`, `"\u03BC"`, `u8"\u03BC"` in an online compiler and the first two came out as nonsense while the last two worked. But in CP-1252, `"\u0085"` is fine (and so is `u8"\u0085"`).